# Error in passing data from the view to the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a button on the view page that connects to the another controller by passing an ID value.

Controller

```
public class CartController : Controller
{
    ......
    [Route("index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var cart = SessionHelper.GetObjectFromJson<List<Item>>(HttpContext.Session, "cart");
        ViewBag.cart = cart;
        return View();
    }

    [Route("buy/{customerID}/{invetoryID}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Buy(int? customerID, int? invetoryID)
    {
        if (customerID == null || invetoryID == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Customer custData = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(customerID);
        var intData = await _context.Inventories.FindAsync(invetoryID);

        if (SessionHelper.GetObjectFromJson<List<Item>>(HttpContext.Session, "cart") == null)
        {
            List<Item> cart = new List<Item>();
            cart.Add(new Item
            {
                Custom = custData,
                Inventory = intData,
                Quantity = 1
            });
            SessionHelper.SetObjectAsJson(HttpContext.Session, "cart", cart);
        }           
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    } }}
```

Model

```
public class Item
{
    public Customer Custom { get; set; }
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

View is like below

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
   .......
    @{var dataCart = ViewBag.cart; }
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.cart)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Inventory.StrainId</td>
            <td>@item.Inventory.StrainName</td>
            <td>@item.Quantity</td>
        </tr>
    }
 </table>
 <br>
<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Inventories" asp-route-id="@dataCart.Custom.CustomerId">Select</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It throws error when I page is loaded it is throwing error like `RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.Item>' does not contain a definition for 'Custom'`

[image]

Even though the Item model and the ViewBag has the `Custom` it throws no  definition. Can anyone tell what I am missing here. If I dont have the button then the page load perfectly fine.

```
 <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Inventories" asp-route-id="@dataCart.Custom.CustomerId">Select</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fix your view

`````
@if ( @ViewBag.cart != null && ViewBag.cart.Count>0)
{
<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Inventories" asp-route-id=" @ViewBag.cart[0].Custom.CustomerId">Select</a>
}
````
or  place ancor inside of foreach
````
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.cart)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Inventory.StrainId</td>
            <td>@item.Inventory.StrainName</td>
            <td>@item.Quantity</td>
             <td>
<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Inventories" asp-route-id="@item.Custom.CustomerId">Select</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
 </table>
 <br>
`````

Comment: No I want the anchor to be outside the table. Which allows the users to navigate back

Comment: Then you will have to post the whole code. If is absolutely impossible to figure where all the pices code you posted from. Where is the get action and get view, where is the post action and post view

Comment: Thanks a ton it works now but  `if ( @ViewBag.cart != null && ViewBag.cart.Count>0)` how to handle this in the view. Because this If statement shows up in the screen

Comment: It was a typo , should be @If